# Fetching an URL in Javascript, encoding problems & IE9

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to solve a problem with in-browser Javascript: I need to fetch an external HTML document as a string. The HTML4 document declare a ISO-8859-1 charset via the http-equiv meta but the server (which I have no control over) does not send the charset in the Content-Type header. The problem is that I don't find how to get a properly encoded HTML string (i.e. ISO-8859-1 characters converted to Javascript's internal unicode string representation).

Here is extract of my external document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title><title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I use a "GET" XMLHttpRequest to fetch the document, I receive the document as text but not with the proper encoding: the document is interpreted as UTF-8 by default as stated in the XMLHttpRequest specification, and the HTML document is not parsed to figure out the charset (except in Firefox I think, but I don't understand why).

I can force the XMLHttpRequest to interpret the result as ISO-8859-1 by using the overrideMimeType method. However, it does not work in IE9.

So I searched a way to change the encoding of the string received, but it seems that Javascript does not provide an easy way to do that.

Then, I searched a way to parse the HTML string as a HTMLDocument, so that the charset is taken in account, and then use outerHTML to retrieve a properly encoded string:

- I tried to use a "document" responseType for the XMLHttpRequest: nice, but IE9 does not return a proper HTMLDocument, so I didn't figure out how to get the outerHTML
- I tried to use DOMParser in "text/html" mode, but it's not supported in IE9
- I tried to create a HTMLDocument with document.implementation.createHTMLDocument, but can't figure how to populate the document in IE9 (doc.write, doc.documentElement.innerHTML, doc.documentElement.outerHTML do not work)

When I use the hidden frame technique to fetch the document, the scripts are executed and I don't want that. I am reluctant to use regexps to sanitize the HTML, because it seems fragile to me and because I need the script elements in my HTML string.

Finally, is there a solution to my problem with IE>=9?

Note: getting a HTML string may not be a strict requirement, I can problably use a HTMLDocument instead on the condition of being able to build one!